# Delete and index and associated data from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {('0hr', '0.01um', 0): 12,
  ('0hr', '0.01um', 1): 10,
  ('0hr', '0.1um', 0): 8,
  ('0hr', '0.1um', 1): 6,
  ('0hr', 'Control', 0): 4,
  ('0hr', 'Control', 1): 2,
  ('24hr', '0.01um', 0): 18,
  ('24hr', '0.01um', 1): 15,
  ('24hr', '0.1um', 0): 12,
  ('24hr', '0.1um', 1): 9,
  ('24hr', 'Control', 0): 6,
  ('24hr', 'Control', 1): 3},
 'b': {('0hr', '0.01um', 0): 42,
  ('0hr', '0.01um', 1): 35,
  ('0hr', '0.1um', 0): 28,
  ('0hr', '0.1um', 1): 21,
  ('0hr', 'Control', 0): 14,
  ('0hr', 'Control', 1): 7,
  ('24hr', '0.01um', 0): 30,
  ('24hr', '0.01um', 1): 25,
  ('24hr', '0.1um', 0): 20,
  ('24hr', '0.1um', 1): 15,
  ('24hr', 'Control', 0): 10,
  ('24hr', 'Control', 1): 5}})
```

I want to create a dataframe with the same indices and columns but with one fewer level on the index axis.

I know I can do this :

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index columns=df.columns)
```

then reset the index to drop the second level:

```
df2.reset_index(level=2,drop=True,inplace=True)
```

but that yields :

```
                a    b
0hr  0.01um   NaN  NaN
     0.01um   NaN  NaN
     0.1um    NaN  NaN
     0.1um    NaN  NaN
     Control  NaN  NaN
     Control  NaN  NaN
24hr 0.01um   NaN  NaN
     0.01um   NaN  NaN
     0.1um    NaN  NaN
     0.1um    NaN  NaN
     Control  NaN  NaN
     Control  NaN  NaN
```

How can I make my duplicate dataframe look like this :

```
                a    b
0hr  0.01um   NaN  NaN
     0.1um    NaN  NaN
     Control  NaN  NaN
24hr 0.01um   NaN  NaN
     0.1um    NaN  NaN
     Control  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `drop_duplicates` method:

```
In [11]: df.index.droplevel(2)
Out[11]:
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'0hr', u'24hr'], [u'0.01um', u'0.1um', u'Control']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]])

In [12]: df.index.droplevel(2).drop_duplicates()
Out[12]:
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'0hr', u'24hr'], [u'0.01um', u'0.1um', u'Control']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])
```

Which you can feed in to your DataFrame:

```
In [13]: pd.DataFrame(index=df.index.droplevel(2).drop_duplicates(), columns=df.columns)
Out[13]:
                a    b
0hr  0.01um   NaN  NaN
     0.1um    NaN  NaN
     Control  NaN  NaN
24hr 0.01um   NaN  NaN
     0.1um    NaN  NaN
     Control  NaN  NaN
```